# Как сгенерировать тестовые данные одного пола

Tags: php, laravel

Использую фабрику из ларавел. Подскажите как сгенерировать фейковые данные одного пола.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если доступ к `$this->faker` каждый раз генерит новый экземпляр, что приводит к  разнополым результатам, то надо сначала его сохранить в переменную.  В противном случаем смотреть как оно вообще работает там

Answer (score 0):

```
    $gender = $this->faker->randomElement(['male', 'female']);

    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->firstname($gender),
        'surname' => $this->faker->lastname($gender)
    ];
```